# test site on different server then live server with same URL

Tags: web-hosting, migration

Looked up this question but didn't see an answer after I queried the title.  I have an old dated site on a shared hosting server that I'd like not to take offline.  Fortuntely, I developed a new site in a different language Im learning but now I want to test it on a different hosting server then what I'm using. The new site eventually will be on the new host after prod testing. I understand that I would need to modify my nameservers but do I need to have all four indicated and how can I only allow myself the ability to test on the new hosting?  I'd imagine the same techniques here are utilized when shifting sites on other servers?  Will I need to hit the IP to test on the new server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to change the HOSTS file on your machine. See [this article](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/) for more information. Essentially you tell your computer that a particular domain has a specific IP address so it goes right there.